# How can I execute Selenide in Chrome using ChromeDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I started using selenide (selenium wrapper api) and must say its a great tool but my only issue is its lack of documentation or usage examples online yet.

Any idea how to run your application coded in selenide in google-Chrome. I am using eclipse as IDE. I have added an environment variable "browser" with value chrome in my run configuration but when I run it picks up firefox.

My stack is 
JDBC
Java
Selenide

Comment: Hi! You don't need to add environment variable "browser", but you need to set system property "selenide.browser" to tests JVM. The easiest way to do it to add this line in the beginning of your tests: `System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "chrome");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");
open("http://google.com");
```

You can find some documentation [here](http://selenide.org/documentation.html).

Comment: While this is true for a starting a general ChromeDriver, this is specifically asking for [Selenide](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide) which wraps Selenium.

Answer (score 5):

The below code will help you launch the Chrome Browser with Selenide, and not with the selenium. It means you don't have to issue a close or quit command at the end of the iteration.

```
import static com.codeborne.selenide.CollectionCondition.size;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.text;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import com.codeborne.selenide.junit.ScreenShooter;

public class SimpleDateFormatClass {

@Rule
public ScreenShooter takeScreenshotSelenide = ScreenShooter.failedTests().succeededTests();

@Test
public void checkGoogleSearchResultsReturnValidResultNumberAndText() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver_2");
    //Doesn't matter chrome or Chrome as this is case insensitive.
    System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");
    open("http://google.com");
    $(By.name("q")).setValue("Selenide").pressEnter();

    // assure there are 10 results in the page
    // static import shortcut, place the cursor on the method and press
    // ctrl+shift+m/ cmd+shift+m
    // $ -> driver.findElement, $$ -> driver.findElements
    $$(".iris li.g").shouldHave(size(10));
    $(".iris li.g").shouldHave(text("Selenide World!"));
}
```

}

This should help you even if you are running from the command prompt/ terminal, but if you want to exclusively pass on the Chrome from cmd you can use the "browser" parameter as below

```
-Dselenide.browser=chrome
```

Comment: Thats it *System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");*

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Selenide what browser to use. That can be done using Configuration properties:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;

public class Tests {

@Before
public void setBrowser() {
    Configuration.browser = "chrome";
}
```

Remember: your webdriver should be placed on the standard path. For unix/linux it is: `/usr/local/bin;`
If your webdriver is located on a different path or renamed -- you need to set a system property with right path to the webdriver. For example:

Windows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program files\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Linux\Unix:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/share/chromedriver");
```

Make sure that your unix / linux chromedriver is executable. After this, you should have a fully working example (in my case, chromedriver is renamed and has version information):

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.junit.*;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver;

public class TestClass {
    @Before
    public void setBrowser(){
        Configuration.browser = "chrome";
        Configuration.browserSize = "1920x1080";
        Configuration.holdBrowserOpen = true;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver_2.33");
    }

    @Test
    public void gotoGoogle(){
        open("https://www.google.com");

        WebElement searchBox = $(By.xpath("//input[@id='lst-ib']"));
        $(searchBox).shouldBe(Condition.visible).setValue("How can I execute Selenide in Chrome using ChromeDriver").pressEnter();

        WebElement firstResultLink = $(By.xpath("(//div[@class='rc']//a)[1]"));
        $(firstResultLink).click();

        System.out.println(getWebDriver().getCurrentUrl());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use this command line switch with Maven:

```
mvn test -P chrome
```

It requires the Maven profiles in the pom.xml file such as are seen here:

https://github.com/selenide-examples/google

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "chrome");` for running in the chrome browser. If the same test you need to perform in safari just change the chrome to safari. 
Eg:

```
System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "safari"); open("http://idemo.bspb.ru/");
```