# Selenide and ChromeDriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, selenide

Can somebody help me, please?
I'm working with Selenide framework using Java. Selenide has method for opening browser. It look's like: 
`Selenide.open("http://www.google.com");`

By default it uses FireFox. For use Chrome I need to set System property, like:

```
   @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        Configuration.timeout=5000;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
    }
```

Chromedriver in my default project folder. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need just simply do this:

```
@Before
public void setUp ()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/chromedriver.exe");
    Configuration.browser = "chrome";
    open ("your link here");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use selenide configuration as below for the chrome browser

```
Configuration.browser = "chrome";
```

You can see this post for more details

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Its selenide configuration. [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768509/how-can-i-execute-selenide-in-chrome-using-chromedriver)

Comment: add this comment in the original post @Vivyen

Answer (score 2):

You are not defining the value of Configuration.browser parameter. By default selenide will launch the firefox browser. In order to launch the chrome you should add following line
Configuration.browser = "chrome";

Following code should work for you .

```
@BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
Configuration.browser = "chrome";
Configuration.timeout=5000;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@BeforeTest
public void setUp ()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver exe file path");
    Configuration.timeout=5000;
    Configuration.browser = "chrome";
    open ("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: @JimHawkins System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver exe file path"); -> setting the property for chomedriver binary ,
    Configuration.timeout=5000; ->setting the property for browser timeout default,
    Configuration.browser = "chrome"; -> Setting the the property for browser to which have to launch,
    open ("https://www.google.com"); -> opens the browser & loads the url(https://www.google.com)

Comment: why don't you edit your answer and insert the comments content ??? It's painful to read the answers and after that search the comments for more informations...

Comment: Ohh! sorry I am first time user. I will keep care of it next time.

Comment: I think Selenide uses WebDriverManager library now, so I don't think it's necessary to specify the Chrome.exe filepath

Answer (score 0):

In [this GitHub wiki page](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/wiki/How-Selenide-creates-WebDriver) there is a nice explanation about how Selenide creates the WebDriver.

As stated in the section "[How to run Selenide with another browser](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/wiki/How-Selenide-creates-WebDriver#how-to-run-selenide-with-another-browser)", you should set the driver by calling

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/your/chrome/driver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

You could take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768509/how-can-i-execute-selenide-in-chrome-using-chromedriver) to retrieve some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the extension *.exe to the filename so, that you have full file name with its extension. I usually add the full path to the file name too. I came across this issue, when I configured webdriver sampler for jmeter. And I had to provide full path to chromedriver in the sampler settings. Later this approach turned out to be right with selenide too. More details about what I've mentioned can be found here - [How to use Selenium with webdriver](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler), perhaps it will be a useful solution to your task.

Answer (score 0):

```
String chromeDriverPath = "/path/to/chromedriver.exe";
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeDriverService Service = Builder
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .withLogFile(new File("./chromdriver.log"))
    .usingDriverExecutable(new File(chromeDriverPath))
    .build();
CommandExecutor commandExecutor = new DriverCommandExecutor(Service);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(commandExecutor, capabilities);
WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver); //Set driver that Selenide should use
```

why you should use Chrome Service read here: http://www.qaautomationsimplified.com/selenium/run-chromedriver-with-chrome-driver-service-to-reduce-script-execution-time-significantly/

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If driver is in your project folder, you can write:

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\packages\\to\\driver\\between\\src\\and\\driver's\\folder\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify all your work with browser's driver just add [webdrivermanager](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) dependency to your `pom.xml` (for Maven) or `build.gradle` (for Gradle). Then add

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
Configuration.browser = "chrome";
```

as a precondition for your tests and they'll run in Chrome. You will not need to download any files. And you can use other browser by changing the value to its name (e.g. "firefox").

Answer (score 0):

At me works so

```
  @BeforeClass
  public void baseSetUp() {
                File file = new File("/path/to/chromedriver.exe");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);}
```