# What is the difference between System.setProperty and Configuration.browser in Selenide?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenide

Here is a reference to the original discussion: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768509/how-can-i-execute-selenide-in-chrome-using-chromedriver)

There were basically two propositions on how to change the browser when executing a test using Selenide.

One was:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");
open("http://google.com");
```

and the other was:

```
Configuration.browser = "chrome";
open("http://google.com");
```

Both seem to do the same thing. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The comment in the original post from **Paul Nelson Baker** explains this:

> While this is true for a starting a general ChromeDriver, this is
>   specifically asking for Selenide which wraps Selenium.

This means following piece of code is used to start a driver using Selenium:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");
open("http://google.com");
```

While following code can only be used with Selenide:

```
Configuration.browser = "chrome";
open("http://google.com");
```

Note that with Selenide both methods are working because Selenide is built around Selenium.

---

If you need more information about it take a look at [Selenide](https://github.com/selenide/selenide) on GitHub.

Basically, `Selenide.open` performs a call on `SelenideDriver.open` where a new instance of `StaticConfig` is created. In the class `StaticConfig` is the call to the static field `browser` located.